# List of all LINQ query expression keywords?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So I've been doing things with LINQ lately and I've been looking online for a complete list of all integrated LINQ keywords and i couldn't find any.

These are some of the ones i know:

```
from in 
let 
group by into
orderby
where
select
```

Are there any others that I don't know about? Where can I go to find a complete list of all the things possible with integrated LINQ?

Comment: Have you tried the most obvious resource - MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to distinguish in your mind between the [*standard LINQ query operators*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397896.aspx) and the operators that are supported in C# by [*query expressions*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx). There are far more of the former than the latter - and VB supports some of them in the language directly.

For quite a bit of detail about all the different operators, and which query expression parts bind to them, you may want to read my [Edulinq blog post series](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/). It's a reimplementation of LINQ to Objects for educational purposes, looking at how each operator behaves etc. [Part 41](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/) is explicitly about query expressions, including a cheat sheet at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the official MSDN documentation [here](http://goo.gl/n9flt). Another good reference can be found on [odetocode](http://goo.gl/01UX1).

**Edit:**

I just wanted to clarify that what you're looking for are the C# keywords for LINQ, not operators.